# Simple On/Off Toggle Component not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've have a simple toggle component in react that im quite not sure why it will not work. Also if im using arrow function do I still have to bind(this)?

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  construtor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {visibility: false};
  }

  toggleVisibility = () => {
    this.setState({
      visibility: !this.state.visibility
    });
  }

  render() {
    if(this.state.visibility) {
      return (
        <div>
          <button 
            onClick={this.toggleVisibility}>Click</button>
          <h1>now you see me</h1>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return(
      <div>
       <button 
         onClick={this.toggleVisibility}>Click</button>
      </div>
      );
    }
  }
};

ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: When you ask a question, please provide more detail on what problem you are running into than "it will not work". Error messages, console logs, etc. It gives us more to go off of.

Comment: Don't use `this.state` in `setState`. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: I'm writting on codepen which gives me "unexpected token =" under toggleVisibility method which Im guessing is from using arrow function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make two changes. Firstly, you can't define functions on your component as arrow functions like that. That's probably why it's not working. (Yes, that does mean you will need to `bind()` the function in your constructor.) Secondly, I would refactor your render to conditionally display your `<h1>` tag only, instead of the entire component.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {visibility: false};
    this.toggleVisibility = this.toggleVisibility.bind(this);
  }

  toggleVisibility() {
    this.setState({
      visibility: !this.state.visibility
    });
  }

  render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <button 
            onClick={this.toggleVisibility}
          >Click</button>
          {this.state.visibility ? <h1>now you see me</h1> : []}
        </div>
      );
  }
};

ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Note this part: `{this.state.visibility ? <h1>now you see me</h1> : []}`. This is an inlined ternary conditional. It's a very common way to either show or hide something in JSX depending on a simple boolean. Use curly braces `{}` to embed an expression in your JSX, inside of which a ternary conditional will return either one result or another. React will not render empty arrays like `[]` as anything at all, making it handy for when you want to NOT render a thing.

Ternary operator conditionals look like this: `someBoolean ? resultIfTrue : resultIfFalse`.

Edit: Also, `constructor` is misspelled, good catch @RyanHarvey.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo. Constru**c**tor, not construtor.

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {visibility: false};
}
```

It works fine with that typo fixed.